# Switch datatype of property from textstring to textarea im Umbraco Backoffice

Tags: properties, textarea, umbraco

I have a property in multiple document types in Umbraco that has the datatype of "textstring". I need to switch the data type of this property to "textarea" in order to allow for more characters and not be limited to 500 characters.

Being new to Umbraco, I am unsure if this can be accomplished in the Backoffice, or whether i need to do it programmatically.

I have full admin permissions to the Backoffice.

Data loss is not an issue, as it is static text that simply need to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible in the back office. Try the following steps:

1. Open the doc type you want to change
2. Click on the 'cog' icon of the property you wish to update, which will access the 'Property Settings' window. This will open a side menu.
3. Click on the 'x' icon to remove the textstring and replace this with
   the textarea type.

You shouldn't have any data loss as a textstring can be updated to a textarea. But I would double check after you change the property type